# How to route Mvc Controller action when there is subdirectory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This type of url works: ABC/CSDS?id=314

Folder Structure:

Controllers - Folder
  ,ABCController - Class
    ,CSDS = Action

Global.cs file has:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ABC", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

How to make change for subdirectory url like

ABC/TESTN/CSDS?id=314 to go to

Controllers - Folder
  ,ABCController - Class
    ,CSDS = Action

Currently it says "The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark the answer as correct, this will help you get more answers in the future and help others find the answer more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a rule like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/TESTN/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ABC", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Warning, not tested, I don't have the tools installed at work :(